# Cannot find source of TelemetryChannel found a telemetry item without an InstrumentationKey

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights, nlog

I have one asp.net core 3.1 console app which basically is a background jobs. I am able to log to the application insight. But there is one persistent log which is logging every  15 minutes which is.

> AI: TelemetryChannel found a telemetry item without an
> InstrumentationKey. This is a required field and must be set in either
> your config file or at application startup.

I have gone through other SO answer and tried the recommended solution but still is am seeing this log. Some of the post I looked on are [How to find the source of "TelemetryChannel found a telemetry item without an InstrumentationKey"](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2070)
[Using nlog with ApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService in .net core 3.1 console app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59420952/6012566)

Based on this recommendation I tried with below code.

```
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(
                    options =>
                        Configuration
                    .GetSection("ApplicationInsights")
                    .Bind(options)
                 );
   NLog.LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<ApplicationInsightsTarget>("ai").InstrumentationKey
                = Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"].ToString();
```

And my app settings has config like below.

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "instrumentation-key",
    "DeveloperMode": false,
    "EnableRequestTrackingTelemetryModule": true,
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": false,
    "EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup": true
  },
```

And package that i am using are

```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" Version="2.14.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.15.0" />
```

Did anyone get luck fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is the existing issue on the package version in 2.15.0 and above.

> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService

I reverted the version back to 2.14.0. That fixed the issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to copy the `appsettings.json` to the application root folder during publishing.
2. Check by adding an application insight resource id to to the csproj:

```cs
 <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/abc</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
```

3. Try update or downgrading the Version of `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService`